# Angular 8: Does Visual Studio Code Debugger Catch Subject Behavior Correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Does setting `formBuilder` in subscription known to cause any problems/issues? When conducting this line, the form values never set, even though it's clearly shown in debugger. However, it never makes it to the HTML screen.

When removing the first subscribe line, and just setting values without a subscription, it works, curious why that may happen.

I just did a console log, once it leaves the subscription brackets } , the values are empty, strange.

```
this.addressCopyFromToMailingService.currentMessage.subscribe(currentMessage => {
      this.editAddressForm.setValue({
        'streetNumber' : "aaa",
         'streetName' : "aaa",
        'city' : "aaa",
        'state' : "aaa",
        'postalCode' : "aaa"...
    });
});
```

[image]

**Basic Service:**

```
export class generalService {

  private messageSource = new Subject();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(currentMessage) {
    this.messageSource.next(currentMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of Observable is `currentMessage`? A `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: hi @ChrisY just posted service code, thanks

Comment: If you are not setting ALL the values then you should use patchValue

Comment: hi @RickyStam yeah, I actually did set all the values just did not show it stackoverflow,

Comment: can you try this.editAddressForm.updateValueAndValidity(); ? After you set the values

Comment: can you show us stackbitz demo

Comment: hi @RickyStam nothing happened

Comment: hi @MadhawaPriyashantha trying to figure out how, my company is so big, lot of it is confidential etc, trying to understand this form behavior

Comment: yes plz, a stackbitz would help a tone to figure it out

Comment: anyone know if a subscription is destroyed, would the values go away in the form?

Comment: Did you initialized this.editAddressForm inside onInit? Also it could be an issue with your html. Without stackblitz we can help more :/

Comment: hi @RickyStam I did this in ngOnInit,  this.editAddressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'mailStopCode' : [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'inCareOf' : [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      'attentionLine' : [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],    should I put it somewhere else? Right now my actual subscription is in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: I usually use "" instead of null but i suppose it's the same. Also try add the subscription inside onInit after you initialize the editAddressForm

Comment: @SailorLuvBoat you don't need to post entire application code.just minimal example with only related code.or reproduce it with new simple code

Comment: I think the problem is the multicast behavior of the `Subject`. Try to use a `BehaviorSubject(initialValue)` or a `ReplaySubject(1)`

Comment: Does your component use the `OnPush` detection strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the multicast behavior of the `Subject`. Try to use a `BehaviorSubject(initialValue)` or a `ReplaySubject(1)`

```
  private messageSource = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

Comment: hi ChrisY, how did you figure this out? given the lack of information in the question, you are correct, it seems like the VS Code debugger is also sending me wrong information

Comment: gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also, thanks !